# Do I need to have 3 RAM chips on a Supermicro C7X58 MB

Tags: memory, motherboard, ddr3, triple-channel

i have a servergrade MB and wonder if i MUST have 3 memory chips to get it to work? i only got one stick with 4 Gb DDR3 Ram.

The MB is a Supermicro C7X58

Cpu: intel core i7-950

i tried to put in just one but i get the memory error on POST: 1 loong beep repeating

Btw: the RAM chip is ECC/Registred

And Also: do i have to use both the 8 pin and 4 pin connector on the MB?

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is No, one should be fine. :)

Most motherboards that support double and triple channel configurations don't require it; you just don't gain the performance of the feature if not using the right configuration (ie: three matching sticks in the right slots).

So I dug through the [Supermicro C7X58 manual](http://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/X58/MNL-1063.pdf) to ensure that standard is in use and it appears it is (P. 2-10 - "Population Recommendation"):

"Performance: **Install one DIMM in slot DIMM1A (the first slot in Bank1)**, OR one DIMM each in slot DIMM1A and DIMM2A (the first two slots of Bank1)."

Your problem seems to lie in your RAM - you state "the RAM chip is ECC/Registred", but the [specs for the motherboard](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Core2Duo/X58/C7X58.cfm) state you need Non-buffered RAM ('buffered' = 'regsitered'):

"1600 / 1333 / 1066 / 800MHz Un-Buffered ECC / non-ECC DDR3 SDRAM 72-bit, 240-pin gold-plated DIMMs"

You should check over their Supported Memory List for that board (it's a link off the Specs. page linked above) to ensure you are getting/using compatible RAM.

HTH.

Comment: +1 you're right, i stand corrected, wait for undeadsoul to mark your answer as correct and i will delete mine. however, for performance reasons you want at least 3 modules. don't want to throttle the mighty power of that Core i7 950 by being cheap on the memory, do you? :)

Comment: Amen to that - just because it's possible doesn't mean it's smart - dropping potential memory bandwidth by 66% on a CPU like this is not a smart way to save some cash.